# Unknown NullPointerException

Tags: c#, .net

Hy!

I want to make a cardgame in c#
The debugger always throws a NullPointerException.
But the var card isn't null (it has a value shown during the debugging)
The problem have to be in cards.add().

My Code:

```
namespace Uno_Logic
{
    class CardStack
    {
        private List<Card> cards;
        public void Cardstack()
        {
            cards = new List<Card>();
        }
        public void fillCardstack ()
        {
            for (Card_Value value = Card_Value.One; value <= Card_Value.DrawTwo; value++)
            {
                for (Card_Colour colour = Card_Colour.Yellow; colour < Card_Colour.Black; colour++)
                {
                    Card card = new Card(colour, value);
                    Card card2 = new Card(colour, value);
                    cards.Add(card); //**here throws the debugger the Exception**
                    cards.Add(card2);
                }

            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Please help!

Comment: Is this the real code?  What does the debugger say about `cards` at that line?

Comment: cards is null but my calling is cardstack = new CardStack();
           cardstack.fillCardstack();

Comment: @user54, You do _not_ have a constructor. See answers below.

Comment: @user547995 - Make the `public void Cardstack()` to be `public CardStack()` and you will be fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace:

```
    public void CardStack()
    {
        cards = new List<Card>();
    }
```

with

```
    public CardStack()
    {
        cards = new List<Card>();
    }
```

constructors in c# has no return type

Comment: Made the `s` letter capital to match the class name.

Answer (score 4):

I think your method `Cardstack` really should be a constructor:

```
public CardStack()
{
    cards = new List<Card>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Then your `cards` variable is null.  You haven't initalized it, because you probably haven't called the `Cardstack()` method. By the way it is better the `cards = new List<Card>();`
 to be in a constructor.

Comment: I think `void CardStack()` was meant to _be_ the constructor. I overlooked the `void`

Answer (score 0):

This is not the `card` variable which is null when the exception is throwing : this is the `cards` variable which is null. Are you sure to call `Cardstack()` before calling `fillCardstack()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to declare a constructor for your `CardStack` class and initialize `cards` there.
If it's so, just remove 'void' before the CardStack method declaration, so it will become a constructor:

```
    public Cardstack() {
        cards = new List<Card>();
    }
```